# Best option for showing place names on sf/tmap map in R?

Tags: r, mapping

I have mapped several locations in Northern Ireland in R. I am using `tmap` and `sf` packages for the first time. There are so many locations that the names of the towns are overlapping when looking at the whole map. Is there a way to set it so that town names only appear once the user starts zooming in closer to a town?

My dataframe is called 'fig2_map_data' and the town names are stored in the 'JBO' column. Here is my code so far:

```
sf_points_ptr = st_as_sf(fig2_map_df, coords = c(x = "Easting", y = "Northing"), crs = 7405)

tmap_mode('view')

qtm(sf_points_ptr, dots.col = "blue", text = "JBO")

dput(fig2_map_df)
```

Here is an image of my current output where you can clearly see the names overlapping. Any suggestion on how I can best format these place names would be much appreciated. I had imagined that they only showed up if the user clicked on the blue dot or zoomed in but I am unsure how to code these ideas.
[image: NI map]

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: add the output of `dput(fig2_map_df)` or `dput(head(fig2_map_df, 5))` . This allows potential solutions to be tested and verified. [Helpful guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added the output. Do you have solution for the question?

Comment: Could you check that the output of the data frame:  `dput(fig2_map_df)` is in the question?